# Codeigniter query result row_array duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I tried to get some records from database, like a ticket system, it's a code which downloading from database results

```
$this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('tickets');
            $this->db->where('t_author_steam_id', $steamid);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $row = $query->row_array();

                return $row;
            }
```

But it's duplicating results, and not showing all results, but only one.
[there is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU52o.png)

Comment: check how many rows it returns

Comment: is t_author_steam_id unique?

Comment: use `$this->db->group_by('');` in youe query

Comment: Ofc, t_author_steam_id is unique.

Comment: Array ( [t_id] => 1 [t_author_id] => 2 [t_author_steam_id] => 31231231231233123 [t_title] => Nie dziala mi to [t_text] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quam repellendus error, itaque, qui asperiores! Illo, similique, inventore. Quis saepe iure laborum at quisquam quia necessitatibus eveniet, architecto commodi. Consectetur, reprehenderit, nam laborum necessitatibus aliquid cumque laudantium expedita nemo incidunt. [t_date] => 1449607485 [t_status] => 1 [t_admin_id] => 1 [t_lang] => 1 [t_amount] => 1 )

Comment: show your view and controller as well !
it seem like you are looping a single record again and again .

Comment: @TomaszChwicewski Please edit your answer to provide any relevant information. Don't post it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Method 01**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tickets');
$this->db->where('t_author_steam_id', $steamid);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();

if(!empty($result)) # this will act as $query->num_rows() > 0
{
    return $result;
}
```

**Method 02**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tickets');
$this->db->where('t_author_steam_id', $steamid);
$this->db->group_by('t_author_steam_id'); # add this 
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();

if(!empty($result)) # this will act as $query->num_rows() > 0
{
    return $result;
}
```

**In view**

```
<?php foreach($tickets as $items){ ?>
    <tbody>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $items['t_id']; ?></th>
        <th scope="row">
            <?php if($items['t_lang'] == 1)
            {
                echo lang('polish');
            } elseif($items['t_lang'] == 2) {
                echo lang('english');
            } ?>
        </th>
        <td><?php echo $items['t_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $items['t_date']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php 
            if($items['t_status'] == 1) 
            {
                echo '<span class="label label-info" id="status">'.lang('items-status-1').'</span>';
            } 
            elseif($items['t_status'] == 2) 
            {
                echo '<span class="label label-warning" id="status">'.lang('items-status-2').'</span>';
            } 
            elseif($items['t_status'] == 3) 
            {
            echo '<span class="label label-Success" id="status">'.lang('items-status-3').'</span>';
            }?>
        </td>
        <td>Zobacz</td>
    </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

> > Method 1 is works fine. Problem is with in your code where you use foreach  loop

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HsNkfkJe It's code where im using loop, but now i had only erros like "Message: Undefined index: t_id", in my controller it looks like: 
`   $ticket['tickets'] = $this->support_model->get_tickets($this->session->userdata('u_steam_id'));
   $this->load->view('support_view', $ticket);

`

Comment: I have a error with this code,  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: check your controller array

Comment: `$ticket['tickets'] = $this->support_model->get_tickets($this->session->userdata('u_steam_id'));
   $array = $this->session->userdata('steam');
   $steamid = $array['steam_id'];

   $this->support_model->CheckPlayerDatabase($steamid);
   $userdata = $this->steamapi->getPlayerSummary($steamid);

   $this->load->view('support_view', $ticket);` i think it's working.

Comment: replace foreach again which i post in answer

Comment: Still the same error. `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/support_view.php

Line Number: 95`
Line 95 is foreach.

Comment: Okay, i forgot to add records in db, i'm sorry, but now i have only a one ticket, where i have 2 tickets. One is showing only.

Comment: And when i login first to the page, i see the error about Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and after reload it's delete.

Answer (score 0):

`$query->row_array()` returns only the first row of all the records. If you want to return all records use `$query->result_array()` instead.